# Mongodb not returning collections

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

I've set up fresh install of mongodb on Mac osx Catalina.

I've updated the command shell to zsh from bash.

Dataset has imported and returns stats but will not return anything for show collections. db.getCollectionNames() returns an empty array and db.x.find() returns nothing.

Mongo shell version 4.4.1 and db.version is the same.

I don't know what's going on here, can anyone help?

Comment: You are connecting to the wrong server, wrong database or you have no collections.

Comment: Thank you! Wrong server